# How to apply FloodFill algorithm(Image Processing) in CameraView of Android?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, android

I have achieved the implementation of FloodFill algorithm in ImageView. But I am not able to achieve it on Camera(Surface View of Android). I'm using OpenCV Library for doing it. I have tried the following code using contour concept. But I am not getting the exact result.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        if (mIsColorSelected) {
            mDetector.process(mRgba);
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
            Log.e(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());
            for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
                Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0,
                        0, 100, 10), -1);

            }

            Mat colorLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 68, 4, 68);
            colorLabel.setTo(mBlobColorRgba);

            Mat spectrumLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 4 + mSpectrum.rows(), 70,
                    70 + mSpectrum.cols());
            mSpectrum.copyTo(spectrumLabel);


        }

        return mRgba;
    }
```

Anybody have an idea that how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by: " But i am not getting exact result." Can you post a sample of expectation and your result.?

Comment: i want the same result as "Dulux Visualizer" app. The above snippet code rendering raw color on the image. but not a transparent color. Hope you got my point.

Comment: @JayaprakashMarshal can you share your  FloodFill algorithm in ImageView code, i am looking same code. it would be really helpful if you share,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does ImageView means that you got results on the Image in cpp?
And the Surface-View of Android mean that it is on the some android App?